# How do I display an array using XUL elements like a table in HTML

Tags: xul

I have an array
`data = [{'name':'Bob','email':'bob@gmail.com'}]`

How can I render this array using XUL elements (like a table in HTML)?
I'm using pure Javascript (do not using any JS framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want it to look? There's [`xul:listbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/listbox) ([example](http://www.xul.fr/tutorial/xul/listbox.xul)), [`xul:tree`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tree#A_tree_with_several_columns), and you can also use HTML table if it's exactly what you need.

Comment: I want it to display like that: http://shopping.cazoodle.com/public/images/caddy_01.jpg (offer lists) Is it well-formed if I use HTML element in XBL files? Currently I'm only using XUL elements

Comment: It is not rare to put HTML elements in XUL (usually in a <description> tag), but I was thinking of using an iframe. I recommend trying all three and picking for yourself, as there are many factors affecting what to pick.

Comment: Yet another choice is a XUL grid ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Grids ) but Nickolay is right. You should try them all (including an html:table right in the XUL, or in an iframe) and then evaluate which one works the best.